# NN Accuracy Saturates After the Very First Epoch with Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to fit a simple Neural Network to predict a binary target using `keras-1.0.6`. The output saturates after the very first epoch. I try playing around with the learning rate (from 0.1 to 1e-6), decay and momentum of the SGD optimizer and with the layers (10-512 hidden neurons and 1-2 hidden layers) and their activation functions of the network, but nothing worked - the prediction accuracy was the same.

My training set has shape (13602, 115) and my validation set has shape (3400,115). The target variable y_train and y_test have values encoded as 1 and 0 (60% are 1's and 40% are 0's). At first, the data was not normalized though when I normalized it I got the same results.

Verifying the output, I see that the model is predicting only 1 class. Sometimes it predicts only 1's and other times only 0's (when I tweak the model).

I also tried to encode the target variable in the shape (n_sample, 2) but the output was the same.

I followed some questions here and googling that suggests tunning the learning rate and not using 'softmax' activation but couldn't improve the results.

Some of the models I tried is below:

The simplest model:

```
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
```

Model 2:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Model 3

```
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Model 4

```
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
```

and to compile and fit the model:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=0.1, momentum=0.0, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train2, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=50, validation_split=0.2)
model.predict(X_test)
```

The output gives either [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...] or [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...]

Does anybody have a clue on what's going on here?

Comment: You have only one output unit. How many classes are you trying to predict with that?

Comment: It's a binary target, so 2 classes. You can map it into one output unit (0 or 1). Keras docs gives binary classification examples with 1 output unit for binary classification.

Comment: Hey, I have this problem too! Maybe try categorical_crossentropy with [0 1] or [1 0] labels?